# Laravel eloquent relationship return without timestamps

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I have usermodel and brandmodel. relationships of those two are as follows.

**Brand Model**

```php
class BrandModel extends Eloquent
{    
    protected $table = 'tbdb_brand';

    public function users() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserModel::class,'brand_id');
    }
}
```

**User Model**

```php
class UserModel extends Eloquent
{
    public function brand() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TopBetta\Models\BrandModel');
    }
}
```

When i try to get brand of user i get following output.

```
"Brand" => array:6 [
"id" => 1
"created_at" => "2018-06-01 07:07:41"
"updated_at" => "2018-06-01 07:07:41"
"keyword" => "sports_settings"
"name" => "TopBetta"
"description" => ""
]
```

what i need is above result without timestamps. how can i modify above source code to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your result by specifying column name when you want to retrieve it. You can write something like this:

```php
UserModel::with(['brand' => function($query) {
    $query->with(['id', 'keyword', 'name', 'description']);
}]);
```

Comment: Can I do the opposite like `without(['created_at', 'updated_at'])`?

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.4, I do something more straightforward like this:

`UserModel::with('brand:id,keyword,name,description');`

This will include only the fields of the `brand` listed after `:`.